# How to upload IPA file to new testflight?

Tags: ios, testflight, ipa

I have my app first version released in app store. Currently I'm working on the second version, earlier i was used Test flight for importing IPA file for testers. But for now They are shutdown and moved into iTunes Store. So my doubts regarding new methods are:

1. How to upload test builds (IPA)
2. I need to import many test builds to attain stable one. Is that possible here?
   like as test flight
3. Shall I need to change version number of test build each and every time?
4. Since i have already released version 1, Is it possible to use same name for 
   test build?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.) In Xcode Product -> Archive and then submit to itunesconnect. (as if you submit it for a new release)

2.) yes, no problem. All new uploaded builds are "prerelease". When you'd like to submit it to the AppStore you choose one of the prerelease-builds.

3.) no, I keep the same version number for all new builds but I increase the build number (you can do that automatically by adding a new run script build phase:

```
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion"  "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

)

4.) yes, just increase the version number to 1.1 and upload it with the same bundle identifier.

Edit: Screenshot

[image: One version, multiple builds]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. few more doubts, about 4th question-shall i need to increase version number of each pre release to 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc.. ?

Comment: no, only after you published one build (aka it's in the App Store) you need to increase the version number

Comment: I added a screenshot. Live version in AppStore is 1.3, my new (pre-release) version is 1.4 with multiple builds

Comment: is there anyway if i want last stable version (currently live in appstore) and the new testbuild side by side

Comment: give it a new version number and both versions (live and pre-release) will live side by side

Comment: Do you need Xcode to upload it to testflight? I have generated .ipa files using phonegap build, but cant seem to find a way to upload it

Answer (score 9):

*React Native Case Using Expo:*

**In Xcode 9.3 go to:**

```
Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader
```

[image]

> 1. Log in with your AppleID.*
> 2. Now you can import and upload your .ipa file to iTunesConnect.*

Keywords: react-native, expo, .ipa, testFlight, Apple Store, Standalone, iOS

Comment: As of XCode 11, ApplicationLoader is no longer shipped with XCode :( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes.

Comment: You must now download an app: Transporter from the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 8):

**React Native Case Using Expo:**

In **Xcode 11** you'll need to `upload` the `IPA file` using `command line`:

```
$ xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file <IPA_FILE_THAT_YOU_HAVE_UPLOAD_FROM_EXPO_BUILD> --username "YOUR_APPLE_ID_USER" --password "YOUR_ITMC_PASSWORD"
```

Example:

```
$ xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file demo-app-1d7ce261-c1ef-47e2-8925-02828bb73418-archive.ipa --username "claudioxyz@gmail.com" --password "tcxp-wwzq-ujse-decv"
```

> NOTE:
>
> The `YOUR_APPLE_ID_USER`, usually, is your iCloud email that you use to log in your Apple-Developer-Account.
>
> The `YOUR_ITMC_PASSWORD` is `NOT` the `password` of your iCloud account. You have to generate it at https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage page:

[image]

Comment: The `Transporter` App can do the work again.

Answer (score 0):

Apple stopped for using `Testflight` directly as it was before.

So now you have to upload build to `iTunesConnect` and make it enable for `Testflight Testing`.

You can refer document for that from [here](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html).